# Data View works but Layout View doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layouts

I created this map on arcGIS 10.2 and was going to finish it in layout view.
The first click on layout toggle gave me a little colored square, second time gave a very tiny square, then nothing.
i tried opening a template then bringing the map into the frame but that did not work either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you see the properties when you right click on the little square ? Size and position could help

Comment: When in Layout view you could try using the Layout toolbar's Zoom Whole Page button, and then edit your question to include a picture of what the whole page looks like, please?

Answer (score 1):

I had a user struggling with this earlier. When you switched to layout view, you saw a very tiny small blue square and that was it. By closing the map and changing the printer/page layout to 'scale to fit' while we were still in data view and then opening layout view it worked.

Next step was deleting normal.mxt and replacing.